# Microcontroller not recognized at USB port when connected via pins

Tags: c, serial-port, texas-instruments, device-manager

Im having issues with my TI LAUNCHXL-F28379D. I have it connected to the laptop I am trying to send data to/from via pins P19 (SCIBRxD) and P18 (SCIBTxD), as well as GND and 5V via J16, using a USB Type B cord to which I sautered pin connectors. I'm sure power is being supplied to the board as when I plug the 5V cable of the USB cable, the RGB lights and 3 other small ones turn on. However, the Computer does not recognize ithe controller at the port - it only recognizes if if it is connected via the board's Mini-USB port. I've also written a C Program which opens the COM port and reads data - but this does not work without my knowledge of the COM port number, usually found in Device Manager. I cannot get any further in my project without the port number and it is very annoying. I will attempt to resauter a new USB cable, but if there are any other possible solutions, or if I'm doing something wrong, please let me know.

Absolutely all feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Can you not iterate through all devices, find the UID of the device you're attempting to I/O with through some method?

Answer (score 2):

The SCIBRxD and SCIBTxD pins belong to the [SCI peripheral](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sprufz5a/sprufz5a.pdf) in the microcontroller. This peripheral implements a UART port (a.k.a. COM port, a.k.a. TTL serial port). It is not a USB port. Nothing useful will happen if you connect it to a USB port, because it is not compatible with USB in any way.

USB-to-UART adapters (a.k.a. USB-to-serial adapters) do exist. There is one built into the LaunchPad. The UART side of the adapter is connected to the SCIB pins, and the USB side of the adapter is connected to the USB port.

Comment: Thank you, this has provided some clarity as to why the pins don't function correctly. Do you know if communication via COM port is possible? Using the USB Mini A cable? As I understand this utilizes SCIAxT/SCIAxR, and none of the other SCI protocols. I've tried this as well, having synchronized Baud rates of PC & controller via Simulink and sending a simple message (binary 1), but to no avail. The number received at the PC is in hexadecimal and with an abnormally large margin of error.

Comment: @kibblesnbytes I do not know about this particular microcontroller. But you can buy a USB to serial (COM port) adapter cable and you should be able to connect that to your microcontroller. The fact that you're receiving *something* means you're probably on the right track.